# How to attach a Python script to a process and let it run in the background

Tags: python

I have a Python script that sends keystrokes, what I'm trying to do is, run the script in a process that's in the background. Meaning that while I'm focused on a different process for example chrome.exe, I want the script to send keystrokes to a process in the background for example test.exe.

Comment: can you show your code.

Comment: @SharimIqbal I'm just simply Importing keyboard and using the keyboard.send function to send keystrokes, not sure what else you need to know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
import keyboard
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
    k = keyboard.get_hotkey_name()
    if k=='p': # change s with another key
        print('p is pressed')
        # OR #
    if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey='p'):
        print('p is pressed')
```

Note: If you want to add a event on <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> You just need to change p to <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd> or anything you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sharim, but where does the attaching the script to a single process comes to play?

Comment: @Kent Try focus on another window and press the key.

Comment: Oh looks like you didn't read the question correctly, the script you provided only prints on console, what I'm trying to do is "run the script in a process that's in the background. Meaning that while I'm focused on a different process for example chrome.exe, I want the script to send keystrokes to a process in the background for example test.exe". 
In other words it works similar to a macro that attaches it self to a process and can run in the background, regardless if you're focused on that process or not.